# I m confused about context

Tags: android

I don't know when to use `someActivityClass.this` and when to use `getApplicationContext()` to set as a `Context` ! What is the difference ? When do I have to use the first option and when do I have to use the second option ?

Comment: http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very small but very important difference in android application code.

**android.content.Context**

Context is an abstract class whose allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

**1. getApplicationContext():** Application context is attached to the application's life-cycle.

**2. LoginActivity.this :** Activity context is live with the Activity's life-cycle and can be destroyed if the activity's onDestroy.

**3. getBaseContext() :** This Context is available to widgets and Views.

For more detail :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

[Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

[Getting the Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144177/getting-the-application-context)