# getApplicationContext() returns null in Application class

Tags: java, android

I have created a `Shopper` class which extends `Application` class for my project. This is how I am trying to get context in the class

```
public class Shopper extends Application {
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

But `getApplicationContext` always returns `null`. Am I missing something? I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21819009/6891637) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144646/6891637) to get an idea on how to do it; but still the same result.

I have added the name of the class to the manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vn.com.shopper">

    <application
        android:name=".Shopper"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/ShopperTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="true">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

Correct me if I am wrong (I might be probably), but I don't understand how having the field `context` as static can affect the value of `getApplicationContext` (this is what most answers are pointing out).

Comment: I tried that. Does not work. Same result.

Comment: why do you need to get context like that? the context will be available in all your activities if you have defined the application class in manifest.

Comment: try `context = this.getApplicationContext();`

Comment: your Shoper.getContext() returns null or getApplicationContext()?

Comment: @NavinGupta getApplicationContext() returns null

Comment: Show code you tried it!

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu I have already posted the necessary code.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: @AjilO. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34751570/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya still nope.

Comment: @AjilO. `android:name=` set full class name .Uninstall old app and run

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya did that just now. No change :(

Comment: @AjilO. any sol. ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No ):. I am going to assume something broke in the project. I am *re-making* the project again

Comment: @AjilO. That's better .Move ahead .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use **static**

```
public class Shopper extends Application {
private static Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}
}
```

And use

```
Shopper.getContext();
```

Comment: I have tried this. Same result. `getApplicationContext` returns `null`

Comment: your code not use **static**. You can't call method getContext();

Comment: In the code I posted it does not show that I used `static`; but the first [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21819009/6891637) that I tried used static and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Application _instance;
public static Application getAppContext() {
        return _instance;
    }
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   _instance = this;
}
```

Now you can easily use getAppContext method in whole app all classes to get application context.